# Why does a coil retain a magnetic field after unplugging the power?

Tags: electromagnetism

I remember that if you connect a coil with AC and then turn off the current, the coil will retain a magnetic field for a (short?) period of time.

How or why does it retain the field after unplugging?

Comment: I can definitely answer this, but I need to understand the setup you have in mind. Are you talking about chopping off the ends of the coil suddenly or just turning off a power supply?

Comment: Just turning off the power supply. Would it make a difference if both ends are suddenly chopped off?

Comment: The end result is pretty similar, but with a power supply it's a lot easier to explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physically, this happens because a changing current generates a voltage which tries to push the charges in the direction they're already moving.
When you shut off the power supply, the current in the coil tries to keep itself moving, but it can't do it forever because of the nonzero resistance in the power supply and wires.

The phenomenon of currents trying to keep moving is called [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) and is a result of [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) which is one of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations).

To see what happens mathematically first, note that coils of wire have [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance).
Actually, all wires have inductance, but when you wrap a wire into a coil it gets a lot more inductance than, say, a straight wire.
Also, power supplies always have some output resistance.
Therefore, at the moment you turn off the supply, you have a series inductor $L$ and resistor $R$ circuit with some current $I$ flowing in it.

The equation for the voltage and current in an inductor is
$$V_L = L \dot{I}_L$$
and the equation for a resistor is
$$V_R = I_R R \, . $$

Since the resistor and inductor form a series circuit, the voltage drops across them must sum to zero, and the currents through them must be equal:
$$V_R = - V_L \quad \text{and} \quad I_R = I_L \equiv I \, . $$
Plugging the resistor and inductor equations into the voltage equation gives
$$I_R R = -L \dot{I}_L $$
and then using the current equation we get
$$\dot{I} = -\frac{R}{L}I \, .$$
Using the initial condition that the current before we turn off the source is $I(0)$, the solution is
$$I(t) = I(0) e^{-t/\tau}$$
where $\tau \equiv L/R$.
So you see, a circuit with large $L$ an small $R$ takes a long time to go to zero current.

Comment: The current has to go somewhere, so you have to add a parasitic capacitance as well. A real coil will resonate at some higher frequency then.

Comment: I wasn't looking for equations, just wanting to know how it works, but still thank you. I will keep gox's comment in mind too.

Comment: @TekiHaken I'm happy to give more of an intuitive explanation if this one doesn't cover what you wanted. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't bother you much, please do give a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: @TekiHaken Could you comment on what you still would like explained?

Comment: So let me reformulate. The AC current, stream of electrons, is conditioned to bounce back and forth. After cutting the power, the back and forth motion is kept going in the coil due to higher inductance, despite weakening over time due to resistance and parasitic capacitance. Did I get it right? Otherwise, I am lost at the current equation I˙=−(R/L)I.

Comment: @TekiHaken Yes, you got it right.

Comment: A simplified model is an [RLC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Series_RLC_circuit), so the current approximately collects at the ends of the coil as the charge of the parasitic capacitance, therefore the electric potential will tend to increase a lot (e.g. you might experience sparkling when detaching the coil from the source). Energy will then oscillate between the inductance and the capacitance ($LI^2/2$ and $CV^2/2$), while being dissipated on the resistance ($RI^2$) of the wire thus damping the oscillations. Smaller the resistance, longer the damping time.